# bind list item array vue data to input value in a form

Tags: javascript, html, laravel-5, vue.js

Hi I have a form and I have a input field in which I have a vue event which allows to take some values and add it to a data a object in the vue js, but I am not able to bind this vue data property to the input value so I would get back when the form is submitted.

My input

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   <ul>
      <li v-for="item in filterListValueEnArray">
         @{{ item }}
         <button @click.prevent="removeFilterEn(filterListValueEn)">remove</button>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <input type="text" v-model="filterListValueEn" @keydown.enter.prevent="addFilterValEn(filterListValueEn)" name="array" v-bind:value="filterListValueEnArray" class="form-control">
</div>
```

vue js code

```
    new Vue({
        el: '#advFilter',

        data: {
            selectFilterType: '',

            filterListValueEn: '',
            filterListValueEnArray: [],
            filterListValueAr: '',
            filterListValueArArray: [],
        },

        methods: {
            addFilterValEn: function(filterListValueEn) {
                this.filterListValueEnArray.push(filterListValueEn);
                this.filterListValueEn = '';

            },
            addFilterValAr: function(filterListValueAr) {
                this.filterListValueArArray.push(filterListValueAr);
                this.filterListValueAr = '';    
            },
            removeFilterAr: function(filterListValueAr) {
                this.filterListValueArArray.pop(filterListValueAr)
            },
            removeFilterEn: function(filterListValueEn) {
                this.filterListValueEnArray.pop(filterListValueEn)
            }
        }
    });
```

I want to bind the filterListValueEnArray in the value of the text field but I dont get back anything when I do in laravel.

```
$request->all();
```

Please assist

Comment: How do you post your array to Laravel? I can't see that part in your code snippet.

Comment: what I mean is that I do not get the input value in  name array when I post the form, I should get back as an array of item.

Comment: Can you please add the submit code to your question? Maybe there is something wrong with your form submit? The form tag and js code should help to see that.